# CSS Pass hover event from one element to the other

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I have a custom CSS animated cursor, that uses minimum JS to follow the real cursor.

The fake cursor is just an HTML element like anything else.

Since the fake cursor (element) is under the real cursor, CSS thinks you're always hovering it.

So if I hover/click a button, it will ignore both events.

What I imagine it to do is pass through the fake cursor, and go to the button event.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of page]

Here's a screenshot of the fake cursor going under the "PLAY" button:
[image: Screenshot of cursor]

As you can see here, the fake cursor goes under the button.

I know I can change it with z-index:
[image]

But now you can see the CSS does not detect the hover event on the button.

How can I have the `z-index`-effect on the page, while at the same time, detect all pointer events? (A.K.A. pass through the fake cursor)

Here's the full code for the cursor:

```html
<style>
body,
html,
* {
    cursor: none !important
}

#follower #circle1,
#follower #circle2 {
    cursor: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0
}

*,
body,
html {
    cursor: none !important
}

#follower {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%
}

#follower #circle1 {
    -webkit-animation: 2s infinite pulse;
    animation: 2s infinite pulse;
    background: #fff
}

#follower #circle2 {
    -webkit-animation: 4s infinite pulse;
    animation: 4s infinite pulse;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {

    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: .2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        margin-left: -.5em
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {

    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: .2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        margin-left: -.5em
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em
    }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {

    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: .2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        margin-left: -.5em
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {

    0%,
    100% {
        opacity: .2;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
        margin-left: -.5em
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .9;
        height: 3em;
        width: 3em;
        margin-top: -1.5em;
        margin-left: -1.5em
    }
}
</style>
<div id="follower">
    <div id="circle1"></div>
    <div id="circle2"></div>
</div>
<script>
    (function() {
        var t, n, e, o;
        t = document.getElementById("follower"), document.getElementById("printout"), n = function(t) {
            return t.clientX
        }, e = function(t) {
            return t.clientY
        }, o = function(o) {
            var u;
            return u = {
                x: n(o),
                y: e(o)
            }, t.style.top = u.y + "px", t.style.left = u.x + "px"
        }, window.onmousemove = function(t) {
            var n;
            return n = t, setTimeout((function() {
                return o(n)
            }), 1)
        }
    }).call(this);
</script>
```

If you would like to see it live, no worries: [www.parkingmaster.ml](https://parkingmaster.ml)

Comment: Just a comment: I tried  you site and found the jumpiness of the cursor (not the pulsing but the way it jumps when I move the mouse) very difficult to follow. Is that discontinuity in its movement intentional?

Comment: It works fine on my PC. I'm not sure why. The full site is written in 100 lines of simple HTML and not many JS/CSS sources.

Comment: Apologi.es, I had the mouse 'down', my mistake. The cursor does follow mousemove smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the easiest solution would be to pass the `pointer-events: none;` to the css of the fake cursor which is just the html element like `div` so, it will do is remove the events like hover or any other cursor events from it.